# Closing the lid doesn't suspend the laptop in Xubuntu but it does in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, suspend, lid

Hi I have a HP laptop dv6. When I use Ubuntu 12.04 and close the Lid, The laptop suspends. However That does not happen when I switch to Xubuntu 12.04 ? What should I do to solve this problem ? May be play with the config file ? but where to find them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

am so dump !! the problem was in the settings ! I changed it from "Do nothing" to "Suspend" in the "closing the lid" box.

and everything is working fine now !